# php send query to database with quotes not working

Tags: php, input, double-quotes, quote

I have a mysql query like following

```
mysql_query("select * from user where name='$name' LIMIT 1");
```

If suppose my input from client side is 'John' there will be MySQL error in my query.
What is the best practice of preventing this?

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Don't use mysql_ functions as they have been deprecated, use mysqli or PDO instead, you will save yourself a lot of trouble in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, mysql_* functions are deprecated and you should use PDO or mysqli_ instead. This two libraries implements prepared Statements which automatically escape your input.

If you want to use mysql_* instead, you have to call `mysql_real_escape_string` to the passed var

```
mysql_query("select * from user where name='" . mysql_real_escape_string($name) . "' LIMIT 1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$query = sprintf("select * from user where name='%s', mysql_real_escape_string($name));
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Make sure $name contains what you think it does (echo it to confirm).